# SemanticZoom is not gracefully

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro

I am using SemanticZoom in my project. it works fine but is not handled gracefully. What can I do to make its work more smoothe?

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is quite vague, the general recommendation I could give you is to make the zoomed in and out views similar in structure. For example, if your zoomed in view displays a mostly-horizontal GridView then your zoomed out view should display a similarly structured, horizontal layout. Consider the Start menu in Windows 8. A FAIL would be if the zoomed out view showed grouped icons stacked vertically - that would be visually jarring. The best practice is to remain consistent between views, just changing context.

If what you mean is the performance of the animation, then it might be that the complexity of your two views is more than you can reasonably show on YOUR hardware. Be happy you discovered this on your hardware instead of your users discovering it on theirs. There is no real resolution to this other than decomposing your two views and reconsidering the complexity of the overall design. Before you do this, test of a simple set of views and see.

Semantic zoom should be easy for the user to understand. More importantly, you SHOULD use it because it is a regular part of a metro application and users are right to expect it. The execution of the animation is hardware based so you should have a fluid transition. However, all hardware is not created equally, so don't push the limits - just make an excellent app.

Comment: I want to make page like on the main screen in Win8. It means: the text on the top and semanticzoom down page. But in this case scrolling on the top of page doesn't work

Comment: Still not clear, sorry. Email me a mock of what you mean and what your problem is jnixon @ microsoft dot com and we'll see what we can do together.